# If one column is empty then fetch data using another column in sql server

Tags: sql-server

In a table  i need to retrive 3 columns :

```
 OrderNumber, ParentOrderNumber, ClientName
```

ParentOrderNumber will always have ClientName
But some OrderNumber will not have ClientName,

In that case i need to get ClientName from ParentOrderNumber.

Can you please help me with sql query

[image]

Attached is the picture of the data scenario.
Here there is no client name available for ETA-454-5687 hence i need to fetch it using the parentOrderNumber (TOR-096-2000) from the same table.

Comment: When you say a column is empty do you mean an empty string ('') or a null.

Answer (score 1):

Use `COALESCE` which is shorthand for a CASE expression:

`COALESCE(expression1, expression2, ..., expressionN)` is shorthand for

```
CASE
WHEN (expression1 IS NOT NULL) THEN expression1
WHEN (expression2 IS NOT NULL) THEN expression2
...
ELSE expressionN
END
```

therefore you can use

```
SELECT ParentOrderNumber,
       clientname,
       COALESCE(OrderNumber, ParentOrderNumber) as OrderNumber
FROM MyTable
```

Comment: Will it work for empty string? His question is about empty string i guess

Answer (score 0):

```
select 
ParentOrderNumber,
clientname,
case when OrderNumber is null or len(OrderNumber)=0 then clientname else OrderNumber end as OrderNumber
from yourtable
```

Answer (score 0):

Use **Right Join:**

Please refer this one look like same question:https://stackoverflow.com/a/39543010/6606630

Answer (score 0):

This can be achieved with a Case Statement

It performs a basic True False style logic and then allows an action to be performed.

```
Select
    ClientName
,   ParentOrderNumber
,   CASE WHEN [OrderNumber] IS NULL THEN ParentOrderNumber ELSE OrderNumber END AS [OrderNumber]
FROM
    tbl_Table
```

Answer (score 0):

I think we need more information from your table.
Have you something like this ?

```
OrderNumber|ParentOrderNumber|ClientName
1|NULL|nameOfTheClient
2|1|NULL
```

Then you will need to join your table

```
select  a.OrderNumber, a.ParentOrderNumber, ISNULL(a.ClientName,b.ClientName) 
from yourTable a
left join yourTable b on b.OrderNumber = a.ParentOrderNumber
```