# If one column is empty then fetch data using another columns where condition in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I need to retrieve 3 columns from a table:

```
 OrderNumber, ParentOrderNumber, ClientName
```

`ParentOrderNumber` will always have `ClientName`, but some `OrderNumber` will not have a `ClientName`.

In that case I need to get the `ClientName` from the `ParentOrderNumber`.

Can you please help me with the SQL query?

[image]

Attached is the picture of the data scenario.

Here there is no client name available for ETA-454-5687 hence I need to fetch it using the `parentOrderNumber` (`TOR-096-2000`) from the table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use **Right JOIN:**

```
DECLARE @tbl1 as TABLE(
    OrderNumber  VARCHAR(50),
    ParentOrderNumber VARCHAR(50),
    ClientName VARCHAR(50)
)   

INSERT INTO @tbl1 VALUES('ETA-454-5687','TOR-096-2000','')
INSERT INTO @tbl1 VALUES('TOR-096-2442_XCODE',NULL,'')
INSERT INTO @tbl1 VALUES('TOR-096-2000',NULL,'ABCDEF')

SELECT
    T2.OrderNumber,
    T2.ParentOrderNumber,   
    CASE ISNULL(T1.ClientName,'') 
        WHEN '' THEN T2.ClientName
        ELSE T1.ClientName
    END AS ClientName
FROM @tbl1 T1
RIGHT JOIN @tbl1 T2 ON T1.OrderNumber=T2.ParentOrderNumber
```

**Output:**

[image]

Comment: can you please show your required result as you have show initial one

Comment: I think it display same as per your requirement, i have also attach output, is it same as per your requirement?

Comment: @SandipPatel - your answer is giving me right data but its taking lots of time. I am getting time out exception as there are thousands of records.

Comment: Let me try out something and if found let you know

Comment: @SandipPatel - That will be very much helpful. Thanks in advance